# Search is not working on my SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, master-page, search-results, search-scope

i am using SP 2010 and i have this issue on my intranet site :

We configured the site URL to open as HTTPS protocol and after that i have error on my search that "We did not find any results"

Can you help me since i think it's related to the access mapping changes as below:

Default :  https:// serverName : PortNumber

Intranet : https://siteurl.domain.com

Any Idea !

regards,

Comment: Have your defined the Alternate access mapping? Are you using any proxy on your server?

Answer (score 0):

On your server run "services.msc" and verify if the search services are running.

The SharePoint 2010 search services are:

1. SharePoint Foundation Search V4
2. SharePoint Server Search 14

Comment: The above search services is started and the default search on another sites is working fine but the https protocal is not and dont have any ULSViewer log about this problem ...